# UI control for multiple recipients in wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am preparing the screen somewhat like SMS screen. I have contacts and want to show one and more than one contact in To field. Could you please tell me which type of control is used in WP7 in SMS screen. Any custom control which I can refer.

Comment: You mean like a comma separated-list of recipients? There's no real control for that, you'll have to build your own control for that and then style it so it looks like the SMS page

Comment: I did the same thing. 1. I create list collection contacts. 2. Convert list into string with commoa separated. 3. Bind this string to Textbox control to show multiple recipients. Issues: 1. If I delete the contact using Keypad cancel button, I dont have index of that contact. Tough to sync the list. 2. If I touch on contact, how to show popup for removing , cancel options as in native app SMS screen.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic (read: raw) implementation of this would be done with a `ListBox` control and a [`WrapPanel`](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-wrappanel-in-depth) set as the container. Bind it to a list of contacts and make sure that you implement a custom item template for each item.